# How can I close file after stream ending?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a stream of sequence of java.io.File. And I use `flatMapConcat` for create new `Source` of file, something like that:

```
def func(files: List[File]) =
  Source(files)
    .map(f => openFile(f))
    .flatMapConcat(f => Source.fromPublisher(SomePublisher(f)))
    .grouped(10)
    .via(SomeFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Is there a simple way to close each file after stream ending? `SomePublisher()` cannot close it.

Comment: Could you please post a code for you SomePublisher?

Comment: @YurySukhoverkhov I use slick and my code looks like that:

`.map(f => SQLiteDriver.api.Database.forURL(s"jdbc:sqlite:$f", driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC")).flatMapConcat(db => Source
      .fromPublisher(db.stream(Table.getItems)))`

So my SomePublisher is DatabasePublisher of slick library.

Comment: did you try `val sources = Source(files)` then your code, then `sources.foreach(_.close)` at the end? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @DanielL. You forgot about `flatMapConcat`.

Comment: I see. Well, you could store those sources as you create them and close them at the end then... something like `f => { val i = Source.fromPublisher(SomePublisher(f)) ; intermediates += i; i }`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found one good way of many ways to solve my problem, but if you have another way I would like to see it also.

```
def someSource(file: File) = {
  val f = openFile(file)

  Source
    .fromPublisher(SomePublisher(f))
    .transform(() => new PushStage[?, ?] {
      override def onPush(elem: ?, ctx: Context[?]): SyncDirective = ctx.push(elem)

      override def postStop(): Unit = {
        f.close()
        super.postStop()
      }
    }
}

def func(files: List[File]) =
  Source(files)
    .flatMapConcat(someSource)
    .grouped(10)
    .via(SomeFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Answer (score 1):

So, if I understand you correctly you do the following: for each file YOU create database object what opens the file. So since you are opening db connections in your code you are responsible for closing it. Since you are working with finite list of files you may store all db connections in a sequence, run your stream and close all connection after streaming ends.

Alternative way is to make your own publisher what will get file name, open db connection, stream from it, close db connection. Second option will allow you to stream from infinite list of files.

If you want code sniplets from me give me your full source for the function and I'll update it.

Comment: Yes, it's correctly. Thanks for answer, but I think about a simple way, so making own Publisher it isn't simple way, is it? I think about making that with `GraphStage`, it looks better.

Comment: I'm not sure how you are going to do it in general but the most simple solutions right now (in terms of number of written bytes) may not be the simplest in general. I tend to open/close connections to db in the same module/object.. logical structure I can say ). So if you are opening all connections before streaming just close all of them after streaming ends. If you are making opening of a connection a part of streaming than open and close in a single graph object. GraphStage is for transforming stream data and not for cleaning up resource allocated somewhere in another place.